# javascript loop and push into every next index

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

```
 function addItemEvery(arr, item, starting, frequency) {
    for (var i = 0, a = []; i < arr.length; i++) {
      a.push(arr[i]);
      if ((i + 1 + starting) % frequency === 0) {
        a.push(item);
        i++;
        if(arr[i]) a.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
  arr = addItemEvery(arr, "item", 1, 1);
  console.log(arr);
```

### What I get

```
[1, "item", 2, 3, "item", 4, 5, "item", 6, 7, "item", 8, 9, "item", 10, 11, "item", 12, 13, 
 "item", 14, 15, "item", 16]
```

### What i want

```
[1, "item", 2,"item", 3, "item", 4,"item", 5,"item", "item", 6,"item", 7, "item", 8,"item", 
9,"item", "item", 10,"item", 11, "item", 12,"item", 13, "item", 14,"item", 15, "item", 16, "item"]
```

so please help me check this out i need a function that can help me push to all n index in the array

Comment: The array you provided under "what I want" is not using valid syntax. There are a bunch of missing `,`

Comment: thanks, I have corrected that @Olian04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base version (excluding the `starting` and `frequency` arguments) can be done with a single call to `Array#reduce` like this. I've excluded `starting` and `frequency` since you didn't define their intended behaviour in your question.

```js
const addItemEvery = (arr, el) =>
  arr.reduce((res, v) => [...res, v, el], []);

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
const output = addItemEvery(input, "item");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the output you desire.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
  pos = 1;
interval = 2;

while (pos < array.length) {
  array.splice(pos, 0, 'item');
  pos += interval;
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addItemEvery(arr, item, starting, frequency) {
  const newArr = [];
  arr.forEach((entry, index) => {
    newArr.push(entry);
    if (index + 1 >= starting)
      for (let i = 1; i <= frequency; i++) {
        newArr.push(item);
      }
  });
  return newArr;
}
```